# pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class with hadoop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, pyspark, pickle

I am trying to I am tring to delete stop words via spark,the code is as follow

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
word_list=["ourselves","out","over", "own", "same" ,"shan't" ,"she", "she'd", "what", "the", "fuck", "is", "this","world","too","who","who's","whom","yours","yourself","yourselves"]

wordlist=spark.createDataFrame([word_list]).rdd

def stopwords_delete(word_list):
    filtered_words=[]
    print word_list



    for word in word_list:
        print word
        if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
            filtered_words.append(word)



filtered_words=wordlist.map(stopwords_delete)
print(filtered_words)
```

and I got the error as follow:

> pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from **newobj** args has the wrong class

I don't know why,can somebody help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue while using spark. Waiting for the solution.

Answer (score 6):

It's to do with uploading of stop words module. As a work around import stopwords library with in the function itself. please see the similar issue linked below.
I had the same issue and this work around fixed the problem.

```
    def stopwords_delete(word_list):
        from nltk.corpus import stopwords
        filtered_words=[]
        print word_list
```

[Similar Issue](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22711)

I would recommend `from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover` as permanent fix.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, it's just because you are defining the stopwords.words('english') every time on the executor. Define it outside and this would work.

Comment: It helps others if you provide example code demonstrating that this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using map over a rdd which has only one row and each word as a column.so, the entire row of rdd which is of type  is passed to stopwords_delete fuction and in the for loop within that, is trying to match rdd to stopwords and it fails.Try like this,

```
filtered_words=stopwords_delete(wordlist.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect())
print(filtered_words)
```

I got this output as filtered_words,

```
["shan't", "she'd", 'fuck', 'world', "who's"]
```

Also, include a return in your function.

Another way, you could use list comprehension to replace the stopwords_delete fuction,

```
filtered_words = wordlist.flatMap(lambda x:[i for i in x if i not in stopwords.words('english')]).collect()
```

Comment: Hi Suresh,thank you for your answer,filtered_words = wordlist.flatMap(lambda x:[i for i in x if i not in stopwords.words('english')]).collect(),this way still gives me the same error,the first one works,but the return type is not a rdd,can you help me ?

Comment: return type will be a list. we are creating a list and appending the words to them in the function.you need it to be rdd ??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is related to stopwords.words('english') line,
you need to determine it in a stable way