# Why do I get PicklingError while parallelizing tasks using Ray in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, ray

I am trying to run a machine learning prediction job in parallel on a huge `pandas` dataframe. It seems like `ray` is a nice package for multiprocessing in Python. This is the code:

```
model_path = './models/lr.pkl'
df = pd.read_csv('./data/input.csv')
dfs = np.array_split(df, 4)

features = ['item_text', 'description', 'amount']
ray.init()

@ray.remote
def predict(model_path, df, features):
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
    pred_df = model.predict(df[features])
    
    return pred_df

result_ids = []
for i in range(4):
    result_ids.append(predict.remote(model_path, dfs[i], features))
    
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

When I ran it, I got the following error:

```
PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class
```

I take it `args[0]` refers to `model_path`. It is just a string, why wrong class? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911539/pickle-picklingerror-args0-from-newobj-args-has-the-wrong-class-with-hado) helps. If you import the class which you want to load in the def, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the remote function can't take more than two arguments. After I tupled the two static arguments, it worked.

```
@ray.remote
def predict(df, args):
    model_path, features = args
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
    pred_df = model.predict(df[features])
    
    return pred_df

args = (model_path, features)
result_ids = []
for i in range(4):
    result_ids.append(predict.remote(dfs[i], args))
```

Comment: Note that you can also add `num_return_vals` to @ray.remote(num_return_vals=2)